# one-hot encoding of an array of floats using just keras

Tags: python, keras, one-hot-encoding

First of, I am new to stackoverflow, so if there is a way to improve the way I formulate my question or if I missed something obvious, do point it out to me please!

I am building a classification convolutional network in Keras, where the network is asked to predict parameter was used to generate the image. The classes are encoded in 5 float values, e.g. a list of the classes may look like this:

```
[[0.], [0.76666665], [0.5], [0.23333333], [1.]]
```

I want to one-hot encode these classes, using the `keras.utils.to_categorical(y, num_classes=5, dtype='float32')` function.

However, it returns the following:

```
array(
    [
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]
    ], 
dtype=float32)
```

It only takes integers as input, thus it maps all values `< 1.` to `0`.
I could circumvent this by multiplying all values with a constant so they are all integers and I think there is also a way to solve this problem within scikit learn, but that sounds like a huge work-around for a problem that should be trivial to solve within just keras, which makes me believe I am missing something obvious.

I hope somebody is able to point out a simple alternative using just Keras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the continuous nature of floating point values, it's not advisable to try and one hot encode them. Instead, you should try something like this:

```
a = {}
classes = []

for item, i in zip(your_array, range(len(your_array))):
    a[str(i)] = item
    classes.append(str(i))

encoded_classes = to_categorical(classes)
```

The dictionary is so that you can refer to actual values later.

EDIT: Updated after comment from [nuric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758922/nuric).

```
your_array = [[0.], [0.76666665], [0.5], [0.23333333], [1.]]

class_values = {}
classes = []

for i, item in enumerate(your_array):
    class_values[str(i)] = item
    classes.append(i)

encoded_classes = to_categorical(classes)
```

Comment: Good answer, I would avoid casting to `str` and use `enumerate` instead of `zip(..., range())`

Comment: @nuric oh yeah, `enumerate` would be more sensible, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `OneHotEncoder` from `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')

input = [[0.], [0.76666665], [0.5], [0.23333333], [1.]]
output = encoder.fit_transform(input)

print(input)
print(output.toarray())
```

Outputs:

```
[[0.0], [0.76666665], [0.5], [0.23333333], [1.0]]
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Comment: This is indeed probably the easiest way to do it, but in this case I was wondering if it could be done without using any other library than Keras.
Thanks for the comment nonetheless!

Comment: @Jeffrey It is a good idea to reuse and not reinvent the wheel unless absolutely necessary. Not sure what problem are you trying to solve by denying yourself access to most useful libraries for your problem domain.